# RestKit: can I map arrays of objects hold into objects that are hold in an array to an entity?

Tags: ios, restkit

Check this JSON document:

```
{
"result": {
    "playlists": [
        {
        "name": "p1",
        "songs": [
            {
            "title": "t",
            "artist": "a"
            },
            {
            "title": "t",
            "artist": "a"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "p2",
        "songs": [
            {
            "title": "t",
            "artist": "a"
            },
            {
            "title": "t",
            "artist": "a"
            }
        ]
        }
    ] 
}
}
```

Can I map only the "songs" from this document without creating any other entity than "Song".  I don't care about the playlists in this case. 
I made a RKEntityMapping for the Song entity.
Now to make the RKResponseDescriptor what keyPath should I provide to match all "Song" entities?

I tried "result.playlists.songs" but that doesn't work.

```
RKEntityMapping *songMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Song"
                                                   inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];

[songMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"title", @"artist"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *songsResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:songMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"/playlists"
                                                                                           keyPath:@"result.playlists.songs"
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:songsResponseDescriptor];
```

Is RestKit powerful enough to do that?

Is there a way to specify that "playlists" is an array and that the "songs" attribute of all its objects have to be inspected ?

I know "result.playlists" would work if I was matching the playlists against a "PlayList" entity but I want to skip that one and go deeper. Is it possible?

Comment: did you try it?Did you read the Restkit documentation?

Comment: well I tried indeed, checking this document https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping but I can't find an answer

Comment: RestKit and a lots of tutorials around it are infamous of being outdated or not an spot or both. @Lithu TV: what part of the documentation are you referring to? Where do they explain how to use the dot syntax correctly? Thanks!